# Нужна ли запятая: "на машине, практически такой же"?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая?

В тот вечер я уехал домой на машине(,) практически такой же, как я видел накануне в дилерском центре.

По-моему, нет. Но как-то не смотрится.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запятая нужна. Это присоединительная конструкция (которая может включаться без союза). Ср. Довольно поздно явился еще гость, *во фраке*. (пример из Розенталя)

Comment: Я понимаю, что бесполезно спрашивать, что общего между примерами у Розенталя и в вопросе, но хотя бы пояснили, какая связь между присоединительной конструкцией и запятой.

Comment: Почитайте уже в конце концов учебники по русскому языку, а не только поисковую строку в своем браузере. Скоро вы потребуете объяснять, почему под ударением пишется именно та буква, которая пишется, а не та, которая должна быть по вашему мнению.

Comment: А на вопрос ответить?

Comment: Спрашивающий ответ принял. А на вас я не хочу время терять. Мне за это не платят.

Comment: А за подобные "ответы" платят? Расскажете, кто и как? 

Не уверен, что ответ принял именно спрашивающиий. Обычно это делает модератор.

Comment: На "заверенную" почту приходит уведомление о действиях с указанием деятеля. Вы и этого не знаете.

Comment: Отчего же? Я готов это сказать всем.
Marina-ja за адекватность данных ей ответов ответственности не несет. 
Так лучше? )))

>К врачу. Срочно.  

Я не врач, но посмотреть могу. Диктуйте адрес.

Answer (score 2):

Ваши сомнения понятны, но думается, они были бы оправданны, если бы определение, стоящее за определяемым словом, было одиночным (такой или такой же), но слово "практически" делает это определение распространенным, а  значит, нуждающимся в обособлении.

Answer (score 0):

можно и без запятой, если не выделять интонацией, тогда это будет необособленное определение.

Answer (score 0):

можно и без запятой, если не выделять интонацией, тогда это будет необособленное определение.

Answer (score 0):

~1. Запятая, полагаю, интонационная, т.е. необязательна. Можно без неё (согласен с тем, что тогда конструкцию надо трактовать как необособленное определение). Но, поскольку предложение достатоно расрпостранённое, лучше поставить. Это как раз то, что вы назвали "без неё не смотрится"

~2. Слово "практически" в значении "почти" - лексическая ошибка. Замените на "почти" -  и рука "сама" эту запятую поставит.